# Создание функции на Си

Tags: c, функции

не гнобите пожалуйста,1 курс гум направления,поставили программирование,вообще не понимаю.

**Вопрос:** Нужно цикл заключить в функцию и вызвать её,вроде просто но на выходе получаю неверное значение.

Сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
int n,x,i;
float sum;
printf(" Введите n ") ;
scanf("%d",&n);
printf(" Введите x ") ;
scanf("%d",&x);

for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
sum=sum+((x+cos((i*x*180)/3.14))/(pow(2,i)));
}

printf("Вывод: %f",sum);

return 0;
}
```

Моя функция :

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int n,x,i,m;
float sum = 0.0f;

float func (int n,int x) {
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
sum=sum+((x+cos((i*x*180)/3.14))/(pow(2,i)));
}
return(sum);
}



int main()
{

printf(" Введите n ") ;
scanf("%d",&n);
printf(" Введите x ") ;
scanf("%d",&x);




m=func(n,x);
printf("Вывод: %f",m);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так функцию-то покажите

Comment: Переменная `sum` не инициализирована. Заменить `float sum;` на `float sum = 0.0f;`. Вынести функцию `func` за пределы `main`.

Comment: показал ,исправил

Comment: wololo, заменил и вывел, но ответ остаётся равным :0.0000

Comment: Напишите какие данные вы вводите и получаете 0? Например у меня просто `float sum = 0.0f;` написать достаточно и выдает не нулевой ответ.

Comment: ввожу n=1 x=1  ..

Comment: это именно с функцией,в программе без функции ошибок нет

Comment: Нашёл ошибку, инициализировал m как int, а функция выводила float,после этого результат вроде бы выдает верным.

Comment: Вообще-то этот пересчет - `*180/3.14` - очень смущает. Если `x` задается в градусах - перессчет обратный, если в радианах - то никакой пересчет не нужен, вся тригонометрия в радианах работает...

Comment: Harry,нам сказали что в градусах должно быть,т.е должен быть перевод из радиан в градусы –

Comment: Что должно быть в градусах? Попробуйте вывести `sin(90)` - вы, наверное, удивитесь, но это совсем не 1...